# Error when trying to pass information to membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, membership-provider

**EDIT: I found the solution to my problem. More information at the end of post.**

I built a WCF service that uses a membership provide to provide authorization for my client and to manage users/roles etc. So far the authorization works great.

I am trying to give my client the ability to register new users, so I have decided to interface the sql membership provider code from within my service and then call those methods from the client, since I haven't seen a way to directly call upon the SQL provider from a client without Client Application Services.

I tried interfacing the CreateUser method in the service and when I call it from the client to create a new user I get this error and can't figure out what is going wrong:

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Here is the code from my service that calls the membership provider directly.

```
public string RegisterUser(string username, string password, string email,
                                                   string passwordquestion, string passwordanswer, bool isapproved)
        {
            MembershipCreateStatus status;
            SqlMembershipProvider mProvider = new SqlMembershipProvider();
            mProvider.CreateUser(username, password, email, passwordquestion, passwordanswer, true, null, out status);

            switch (status)
            {
                case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
                    return "Username already exists. Please enter a different user name.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                    return "A username for that e-mail address already exists. Please enter a different e-mail address.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
                    return "The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
                    return "The e-mail address provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
                    return "The password retrieval answer provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion:
                    return "The password retrieval question provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
                    return "The user name provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError:
                    return "The authentication provider returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected:
                    return "The user creation request has been canceled. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

                default:
                    return "An unknown error occurred. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";
            }


        }
```

Here is the code I am calling from my client:

```
private void CreateUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            wsBasicAuthService.BasicAuthService c = new wsBasicAuthService.BasicAuthService();
            c.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Password);
            c.RegisterUser("myUserName", "password", "email@test.com", "question", "answer", true, true);


        }
```

I have noticed that it adds an extra parameter by itself to the c.RegisterUser argument call "isApprovedSpecified", although I don't think that has anything to do with it.

I am new to memberships and services and having a hard time switching over to C# from vb.net so if anyone could steer me in the right direction I would be more than appreciative.

**Solution:** After I set includeExceptionDetailInFaults as true in the web.config file, I was able to quickly figure out it was an object reference issue. So I figured the membership provider must not of been instantiated properly. That was it. Here is how it should of looked.

```
SqlMembershipProvider mProvider = (SqlMembershipProvider)Membership.Providers["membershipProvider"];
//membershipProvider is the name you have configured for your provider in the web.config file.
```

Comment: put the `c.RegisterUser` call in a try catch block and see what the exception is.

Comment: I actually had includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" in the web.config. After I turned it on the exception is : (Object reference not set to an instance of an object). So it leads me to wonder what I am missing here.

Comment: Where in Web.Config did you add includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"